# Bootstrap - Best practices on nesting - rows & spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row, nested

**What's the best way to use nesting.**

Multiple spans inside row - *dynamic content* :

- One row per 12 columns ?
- OR, One row for ANY number of columns ?

**Sample case n°1** - which one is the best & why ? :

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="span6"></span>
    <span class="span6"></span>
    <span class="span6"></span>
    <span class="span6"></span>
</div>
```

**Or**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Sample case n°2** - More levels to organise the content.

Here, use the div "my_margin" to add some margin at left & right - and you must have "first_row" around it.

**So it's :** row-->span10,offset1-->row-->SPANS

```
<div id="first_row" class="row">
    <div id="my_margin" class="span10 offset1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
            <div class="span6"></div>
            <div class="span6"></div>
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Or,**

**You shouldn't use the span10,offset1 but direct margin;**

In that case, you must create rules for each @Media_size to make it responsive.

```
<div style="margin-right:XYpx; margin-left:XYpx" class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

**Or - Spans are 'supposed' to be use for your main contents, and then you just play with css. So, something like that :**

```
<div row>
    <div class="span6">
        http://jsfiddle.net/JkPhw/
    <div class="span6">
    <div class="span6">
        http://jsfiddle.net/JkPhw/
    <div class="span6">
</div>
```

Comment: Won't you get problems when adding left/right-margin to a grid row? Or are you using the fluid grid?

Comment: Well yes, it's a bit tricky; For the moment i'm using the first solution in sample 2; But i'm not sure it's the way you are supposed to use Bootstrap spans. In some case i end up with row-->span-->row-->span-->row-->span-->row... wich seems too much, but it's what i need. I wonder if bootstrap spans are originaly supposed to be used to organise the "main" boxes on your page & then you just use normal css to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To case n°1:**

It depends, if you have for example a list of nine teasers where three teasers fill a line, I'd do it with one row:

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="span4"></li>
    <li class="span4"></li>
    <li class="span4"></li>
    <!-- six more -->
</ul>
```

If you're using the grid for layouting a form, I'd make a row for each label-input pair:

```
<!-- one label-input pair does not fill the whole content width -->
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span3"></label>
        <input class="span5" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span3"></label>
        <input class="span5" />
    </div>
    <!-- and so on -->
</form>
```

I think you shouldn't make a grid and put your content in the different grid cells to layout it, but build semantically correct markup and apply the grid to layout the content (tiny difference).

PS: keep [box-sizing](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html) in mind.

**To n°2:**

I don't quite get the idea there, if you're using the grid, you shouldn't apply left/right-margin to it. The grid depends on its horizontal margins to work properly... if you have to change this to match your frontend with the design it's probably not in the grid anymore.

Update: I'd most certainly use your first example though, if you have smaller content. But use the correct grid span widths:

```
<article class="row">
    <header class="span12"></header>
    <div class="span10 offset1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span5"></div>
            <div class="span5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: More info about n°2 in 'my case' --> frenchdelicious.com/tmp.jpg

Comment: Oh well that's great, six spans in a 10 row :D. This actually isn't in your grid anymore, it will only "work" if you have a fluid grid because the spans then adjust inside whatever row you give them. But keep in mind that because of the percentage margins, you would have slightly smaller spaces between the spans than on the rest of the page...

Comment: I see what you mean, but should i get rid of those spans and row & make it "by pure CSS" ?